# change text color of menu item in options menu

Tags: android

I'm trying to change the text color of menu item in options menu.
i read here many similar question and answers saying it's impossible via theme and style and only via code. i also tried the code example and it didn't work.

I manage to change the background using these theme attributes:

@drawable/menu_hardkey_panel_holo_dark
@drawable/menu_hardkey_panel_holo_dark
#ffffff
#ffffff

but i can't make the text color to change.
i saw an answer suggesting using android:itemTextAppearance but it didn't work as well.

I'm using Android 4.0 SDK.

any help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks,
Gidi

Answer (score 0):

You can not change this it comes by default in android API. If you make changes then it is not work for different version of android device.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.my_menu, menu);
    getLayoutInflater().setFactory(new Factory() {
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(String name, Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
            if (name .equalsIgnoreCase(“com.android.internal.view.menu.IconMenuItemView”)) {
                try{
                    LayoutInflater f = getLayoutInflater();
                    final View view = f.createView(name, null, attrs);
                    new Handler().post(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            // set the background drawable
                            view .setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.my_ac_menu_background);

                            // set the text color
                            ((TextView) view).setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                        }
                    });
                    return view;
                } catch (InflateException e) {
                    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {}
            }
            return null;
        }
    });
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Comment: can you please help me understand what do you mean by menu.xml?

Comment: that's what i thought. but my menu xml uses <menu> </menu> and when i try to use your code it gives me errors. Thanks!

Comment: my menu xml uses <menu> </menu> and when i try to use your code it gives me errors. Thanks!

Comment: i tried to search such an example, and couldn't find something relevant. do you have something available? THANK A LOT!

Comment: Hi Segi, any chance to get an example?

Comment: you should google it. i can not provide you all things. you should try yourself. i can only help you little..

Comment: thanks. believe me i tried to Google it a lot! anyway, thanks for your help.

Comment: yes i did. my problem is with adding the <item name="android:itemTextAppearance">@style/custtextcolor</item> to menu.xml, my menu.xml is using <menu> </menu> tags and i can't add this line between these 2 tags

Comment: thank you for your help, it doesn't seems to work since i don't have any item equals IconMenuItemView for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Kotlin and the new Navigation component and I was able to change this by adding this line to my theme:

```
<item name="android:actionMenuTextColor">@color/white</item>
```

And then manually updating the theme applied to my toolbar like this:

```
toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar)
toolbar.popupTheme = R.style.AppTheme
```

Here's the difference:
[image]
[image]